# Why was Mafalda Hopkirk a "pleasant heliotrope?"

Tags: harry-potter, polyjuice-potion

When you put some hairs/essence of a person into a Polyjuice Potion, the potion ends up a color that roughly represents the person.

Mafalda Hopkirk, as a Ministry witch under the corrupt Voldemortian Ministry, was a very bad person by the time Hermione Polyjuiced herself into her, but the Polyjuice Potion that Hermione drinks is described as being a “pleasant heliotrope”.

Now this is heliotrope:

[image: Heliotrope colour]

Looks like a nice color to me.

So why was Mafalda Hopkirk such a “pleasant heliotrope?”

Comment: Any canon source for the colour of Polyjuice potion representing the person? Seems like the answer here is just "Because she was."

Comment: I recall that Goyle's potion looked horrible

Comment: Who says Mafalda Hopkirk was a very bad person? I don't recall any indication of that in the book. She is never actually described at all, as far as I can recall; only her letters to Harry for improper use of magic are seen. So why wouldn't she be a pleasant heliotrope in Polyjuice form?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Plenty. Crabbe or Goyle’s is described as being the colour and consistency of boogers, while Harry’s is a clear, bright gold. We don't know what Bellatrix’ colour was, but she apparently tasted worse than Gurdyroots. There are probably more examples; the colour and taste of Polyjuice Potion is, as far as I can recall, completely consistently represented as fitting how we perceive the person in question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, she was part of the ministry when it turned evil,  and so she was almost in the middle evil, one of the heads, so it makes sense to say that she was part of the corruption of the Ministry.

Comment: No, that makes no sense whatsoever. There are plenty of people working at the Ministry when it is taken over by Voldemort—they didn’t all suddenly just turn evil. Many (if not most) Ministry employees were good people who kept their jobs by keeping a low profile and probably trying to discreetly minimise the damage the new leaders of the Ministry were doing. Or do you also consider Arthur Weasley and Kingsley Shacklebolt (both of whom continued to work at the Ministry after its change in administration) to be very bad people? Or Reg Cattermole whose Muggle-born wife was being interrogated?

Comment: Remember what Percy said when he joined the Battle of Hogwarts - the Ministry wasn't letting people quit.  Good or bad, you either stayed or you went on the run.

Comment: @HarryJohnston He didn't actually say quite that, though. He said it's _not so easy_ finding a way out at the Ministry at the moment because they're imprisoning traitors all the time—presumably, if you managed to find a plausible way of leaving (“I've been headhunted by Gringotts” might work), you could still quit your job without being imprisoned. They definitely weren't making it easy for people, though, which is a very good point.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Didn't Moody warn that Harry's would "Taste like goblin piss"?

Comment: @Aww_Geez Only in the movie, not in the book (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm at a loss to find anything that confirms that Mafalda was a "very bad person". She was certainly working for the Ministry both before and after Pius Thicknesse took over, but there's no special indication that she was in any sort of position of authority or that she wasn't simply keeping her head down and getting on with her job.

Percy (in Deathly Hallows) mentions that by the point that it had become obvious that the Ministry was under the control of dark forces, that anyone who quits the Ministry would probably be labelled a traitor, with all the consequences that implies to them and their families.

> ‘It’s been coming on for a while,’ said Percy, mopping his eyes under
>   his glasses with a corner of his travelling cloak. ‘But I had to find
>   a way out and it’s not so easy at the Ministry, they’re imprisoning
>   traitors all the time. I managed to make contact with Aberforth and he
>   tipped me off ten minutes ago that Hogwarts was going to make a fight
>   of it, so here I am.’

---

Best guess is that Hopkirk was actually quite a pleasant person, whose job simply involved sending letters and missives on behalf of more powerful people.

As noted in a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/43655/janus-bahs-jacquet), she does take the time to go above and beyond when it comes to signing off her letters, implying that she's normally quite cheerful.

> *We would also ask you to remember that any magical activity which risks notice by members of the non-magical community (Muggles) is a serious offence, under section 13 of the International Confederation of Warlocks’ Statute of Secrecy.*
>
> ***Enjoy your holidays!***
>   Yours sincerely,
>   Mafalda Hopkirk
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets: Chapter 2 - Dobby's Warning</sup></sub>

and

> *As you have already received an official warning for a previous offence under Section 13 of the International Confederation of Warlocks’ Statute of Secrecy, we regret to inform you that your presence is required at a disciplinary hearing at the Ministry of Magic at 9 a.m. on the twelfth of August.*
>
> ***Hoping you are well,***
>   Yours sincerely,
>   Mafalda Hopkirk
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix: Chapter 2 — A Peck of Owls</sup></sub>

Comment: The warning that she sent Harry in his second year, ending with “Enjoy your holidays!” would seem to support the pleasant person theory.

Comment: "There are hardly any excesses of the most crazed psychopath that cannot easily be duplicated by a normal kindly family man who just comes in to work every day and has a job to do."  Terry Pratchett, Small Gods. There are all indications that Mafalda is a good and pleasant person who is just doing her job. Unfortunately, she is doing a "good job, nicely done" for bad people. Nothing specifically evil or vile, she is jut being a small bureaucrat helping the well oiled machine of oppression happily tick. Just a cog in the machine, just following orders, in a way.

Answer (score -1):

Heliotrope is the name of one of the characters in *The Little White Horse*, one of J.K. Rowling's favorite books as a child. Miss Heliotrope had a very kind heart, and was also very well-mannered and proper. So I'm guessing the heliotrope color of Mafalda Hopkirk's polyjuice potion was meant to signal that she was a very nice person.

Comment: Can you provide some evidence that Rowling had an affinity for this book?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_White_Horse#cite_note-6