# Are heliopaths a figment of Luna's imagination?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures

In OotP Luna Lovegood claimed the Minister of Magic had a secret army of fire spirits called heliopaths. The fact that Luna spoke of such beings in itself is seen by others as reason enough to doubt their existence but I've wondered if this was one instance Luna was right (that they existed, not that they were the MoM's goon squad). Was it ever revealed whether or not heliopaths existed outside Luna's mind?

Comment: At least in the books, no mention or proof of heliopaths existing is present. Maybe J.K. might've mentioned it though in one of her interviews or on Pottermore though

Comment: If heliopaths do exist, I can only assume they too must be a [pleasant heliotrope](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/125941) in colour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think we can safely say that they're imaginary. Their sole mention is in Order of the Phoenix. Hermione immediately discounts their existence and they don't appear in the book [Fantastic Beasts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them).

> ‘What are Heliopaths?’ asked Neville, looking blank.
>   ‘They’re spirits of fire,’ said Luna, her protuberant eyes widening so that she looked madder than ever, ‘great tall flaming creatures that gallop across the ground burning everything in front of –’
>   **‘They don’t exist, Neville,’ said Hermione tartly.**

If they do exist, they're surprisingly well hidden for such large and ostentatious creatures.

Comment: If Hermione doesn't know about something, then they don't exist ;)

Comment: @Dawny33 - She's usually quite reliable in these matters.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't being sarcastic.  :)  She chooses her words very carefully!

Comment: @Dawny33- Like how that old bat knew Kamino didn't exist because it didn't show up in her archives?

Comment: @Dawny33 She didn't know about Hallows; but it did exist. Even she can be wrong sometimes :)